# Return a raw pointer to a smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a script like this:

```
void main(){
  vector<int*> objectCollection;
  objectCollection.push_back(1);
  objectCollection.push_back(5);
  objectCollection.push_back(-4);

  vector<int*> newCollection
  for(auto* itr: *objectCollection){
     std::unique_ptr<int>* obj(new int);
     someoperation(*itr,obj);
     newCollection->push_back(itr);
}

void someoperation(*int raw, &int processed){
  std::unique_prt<int> k(new int);
  k= raw+1;
  processed = k.release();
}
```

From here, some operation gives back a "raw pointer" to obj, but obj is in a smart pointer in the script. Is there anyway to make a raw pointer content back to the smart pointer? and then make a vector for the smart pointers?

Hope rephrase makes it more clear

Cheers

Comment: What is the purpose of the `unique_ptr` in this context? Why do you even need dynamic allocation here? And what does `someoperation` do with the pointer?

Comment: It's completely unclear what the question is. Or what this code fragment is intending to do, or what any of these things are. Please see [ask].

Comment: Why do you want a pointer to your unique_ptr?

Comment: why is there an extra * in `std::unique_ptr<myClass>*` ? ishouldn\t it be `std::unique_ptr<myClass> obj(new myClass)`?

Comment: Hm... sorry, but this code has great dependence on my experiment framework. We have our own class for definition on physical objects.

someoperation(*itr, obj) is to do some modification for the content of *itr, and it will return a raw pointer back to obj. 

Here is the question, the function will give a raw point to obj, but if obj is in the format of smart pointer, it would not allow it to be in the function

Comment: *"and then make a vector for the smart pointers"* your `newCollection` is a vector of regular pointers, do you want the `newCollection` to be smart pointers that *own* the pointers from `objectCollection`?

Comment: I'm very confused by your code, TBH. It doesn't even compile (let alone makes sense) :( You have two vectors of pointers yet you push **plain** `int`'s into them, you don't use `std::make_unique()`, your **range for** looks very strange (and is very likely incorrect), both `*int` and `&int` are **invalid** types in C++...

Comment: The multiple errors in the code make it harder to understand what you're even trying to do.

Comment: See a way to make the question clearer, here: [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::unique_ptr::get()` which returns a raw pointer for the underlying object, while leaving the ownership to the smart pointer. Keep in mind that since the ownership it's still the same, `unique_ptr` will still try to delete the object when its scope ends, so don't allow `someOperation` to delete it!

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get

Comment: Hi,
you mistook my question. I am not going to return a smart point back to a raw pointer. Instead, i was to give a raw pointer back to a smart pointer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question (as many others seem to). I think you should try to rephrase it, and possibly add the signature of the method you're trying to call. As it is, I don't understand what you want to do.